# ASCII to Black and White BMP, then Compression

Tags: c++, graphics, character-encoding, ascii, bmp

My first question ever, so I'll try to be as descriptive as possible.

I have a TFT display that I have connected to an embedded processor's bus (64kb RAM, no OS obviously).  I wrote a C++ class to set pixels on the display.  My goal is to print letters.  Each pixel of the letter only needs to be described by 1 bit: on or off.  I imagined making a header file of the following format:

```
#ifndef ABC_H
#define ABC_H

namespace ABC{
    const unsigned int a[]={0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
}

#endif
```

The character above, which I have called "ABC::a", represents a thin white box with a black box on top and bottom.  I have a program that turns bmp files into a header file above.  The array is 32 ints long, and each int is 32 bits (I will probably use uint32_t in the final draft, so don't worry!).  This effectively means that I've described one ASCII character as a 32x32 bmp.  To print it at a specified (X,Y) coordinate, I would just need to do this:

```
void PrintChar(const int* c,X,Y){
    for(unsigned int y=0; y<32; y++)
        for(unsigned int x=0; x<32; x++)
            if(c[y] & 1<<x)
                SetPixel(x+X,y+Y); //SetPixel(x,y) lights up a pixel at coordinates (x,y) on the display
}
```

Question: What would be a good way to generate 32x32 bmps of ASCII characters, preferably not tediously by hand with paint.exe.  Alternatively once, does someone have a better means to the end that I want (like skipping the middleman program somehow)?  Alternatively twice, am I just being dumb and there's a much better way to describe ASCII characters for my purposes?

Note:  I realize using C++ for an embedded processor is a questionable practice (at least I think so) but that's what I was instructed to do.  /shrug

edit:  Ignore the compression part!  I'll handle that on my own (unless you really want to share some ideas, then fire away!).

Comment: Pick a font, draw to an inmem bmp, read pixels, store as const unsigned foo[]

Comment: I've never done anything like that before.  How do I draw to an inmem bmp?  I'm trying to look it up but I can't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any graphics library to draw characters to a buffer, and then construct your character data from the buffer.

On Windows, the most obvious way would be to use GDI+ and ClearType, or you could take a look at [Cairo](http://www.cairographics.org/tutorial/#L1understandingtext). If you want full control over character rendering, I suggest using [Freetype](http://freetype.org).

Once you have a buffer containing the character, you might need to test individual pixesl whether they should be black or white (because graphics libraries might apply anti-alias). Alternatively, depending on how you draw the text and which font you use, it might not use anti-alias at all.

Comment: Freetype was a fantastic suggestion.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The below is Terminal font. Each letter is 8 pixels wide by 10 pixels long. Each division of 8 characters (80 per letter) corresponds to a single vertical band in the letter. For example the letter a below has the first 8 numbers as 0, this means the first vertical line is white.

```
a: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
b: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0
c: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0
d: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0
e: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0
f: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
g: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0
h: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
i: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
j: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
k: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0
l: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0
m: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0
n: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0
o: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0
p: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
q: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1
r: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0
s: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
t: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
u: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
v: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
w: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0
x: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
y: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
z: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0
```

And those correspond to this image's letters:

[image: Terminal Font Image]

Comment: How in the heck did you do that!  If anything it's a start.

Comment: @Aggieboy: He probably just took some bitmap font, like "Terminal", and just extracted the bitmaps from it.